# Check if a file is a system / OS file?

Tags: java, file, file-io, operating-system

In **Java**, is there a way to check if a given `File` object is a protected system file?

Some examples of `File` objects which I'd expect to be classified as protected:

Windows

```
C:\WINDOWS\
C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
```

Others

```
~/Library/
/Library/
/var/
/sys/
/bin/

etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

What is a system file is highly system dependant. Windows Explorer has a notion of system directories which it tries to hide from users.  On Linux/Unix you could look at who owns the directories.

Generally speaking, you don't need to know this as the file permissions controls whether you can read/write/execute a file.

How will you use this information, in a way that permissions won't do for you?

Comment: Hi Pete, I'm creating a backup solution where I want to automatically copy files from a user's hard drive to some other location. If we're going the ownership route, I'd need to be able to copy any files that are NOT owned by the OS itself (root). This will include files belonging to other users.

Comment: @Redandwhite To do that reliably you need to be root. You may want to backup system files like passwd, shadow and fstab. The only thing you might avoid is a backup of the software if you assume you will be restoring this from a CD/DVD. The best approach is to get a complete list from a clean system and use this to build a list of directories or files to ignore.

Comment: I think the restoration process is the most important. I think it makes sense to avoid restoring files that already exist on the host computer. Do you think that's a sensible alternative?